# Load own font in QT 5.10 with Python (PyQT 5.10)

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5

I try to load a own font in a Python application on CentOS 7 (Python 3.6.2) with QT 5.10 and PyQT 5.10 installed. I try it with the following code:

```
id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("/PATH/party.ttf")
_fontstr = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0)
_font = QFont(_fontstr, 8)
app.setFont(font)
```

However, I receive:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'at'

I checked that the font file is found, i.e., id != 1, its 0.

Furthermore, I checked:

```
print("%s." % (type(QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(id))))
```

I expected the type to be QStringList as proposed by the manual (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#applicationFontFamilies) but this seems to be not the case. I also cannot call other methods like removeDuplicates() without the error that there is no corresonding attribute in list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, since pyQt 5, python `str` objects are used where `QString`s are expected and expected `QStrinList`'s behave accordingly. So, in this case, just do it the python way:

```
_fontstr = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(id)[0]
```

Comment: The [0] solve the access problem. But QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(id).removeDuplicates()
still gives an Error (the missing s was a typo in the posting not in the code). .removeAt(0) does not work either.

Comment: Okay perfect. Thanks.